# Which manifolds have no translation invariance?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

On a $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $M$ one can obtain geometric quantities that does not change under the action of the translation group $g_a(x) = exp(a_\mu(x) \partial^\mu)$ which translates each point $x$ locally by the vector $a_\mu$. An example is the scalar curvature $R$.

Are there other manifolds, where local translation invariance does not hold?

Comment: Why do you think that Ricci scalar is invariant under translations?

Comment: The group of translations does not in general act on a manifold; the formula that you wrote is not well defined. The meaning of the question you are asking  in the end is totally unclear. Voting to close.